# Keeping track of moves when pre-processing graphs

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I am writing an algorithm in MATLAB to pre-process a large graph for use with a path-finding algorithm, and I am curious as to the best way that I can keep track of my moves in order to be able to reconstruct the solution and project it onto the original graph.

The pre-processing methods I am using so far are relatively simple; 3  techniques I am using are:

**1) Remove long edges:**
Any edge `(a,b)` that can be reached by sequence `(a,c,b)` where `(a,b) > (a,c)+(c,b)`, is removed

**2) Remove vertices with degree 1**
If a vertex with one edge coming out of it is not either the start or end-point of the path, then that vertex will never be part of the path, and it can be removed

**3) Remove vertices with degree 2**
If a vertex `b` has two edges coming out of it, then `b` can be removed and edges `(a,b)` and `(b,c)` can be replaced by a single edge `(a,c)` with length `(a,b) + (b,c)`.

The algorithm iterates through these 3 techniques until no further changes are possible in the graph, at which point it removes all the empty rows and columns in the graph adjacency matrix and returns the reduced graph for use with the path-finding algorithm.

The pre-processing algorithm works great, in some cases I am able to achieve a reduction of around 70% in the graph size, and my path-finding algorithm is able to find a path of the same quality as the un-processed graph but an order of magnitude faster.

My problem now is in reconstructing the solution on the original graph, so-called "post-processing".

I feel like I should be keeping track of all the moves my pre-processing algorithm makes and then applying them in reverse order after it has finished, I am just not quite sure how I should go about that..

Here is what I had in mind:

- First, keep track of all the empty rows and columns I removed from the matrix after pre-processing and re-insert them.
- Then have a simple vector with indices representing the move number and the value representing what type of move.
- then have one cell array for each of the 3 move "types" containing the data from each move in the order they were performed, with their own iteration counter.
- then if i iterate backwards over the move list, it will tell me which cell array to access, and then i can apply the reverse operation that is next on that list (kind of like a stack data structure)

this seems a bit unwieldy to me, so I was wondering if anyone else had any ideas as to a good method of keeping track of my moves that is easily reversible?

**EDIT:** I thought about posting this on the computer science stack exchange; but my question isn't really about the pre-processing methods themselves, but about data storage and retrieval and the implementation itself. But feel free to migrate it if you think it would be better suited elsewhere

Comment: What exactly would be the your final output? A graph with different colors (reduced graph=1 color, removed vertices=1 other color)? As many graphs as your steps?

Comment: i mean a graph as in from graph theory, not a plot; if that is what you meant. but if not, the input to the pre-processing algorithm would be a graph, `G`, as represented by an adjacency matrix and its output would be `G'` ('g dash', the reduced graph) and some list of moves (a map to get from `G` to `G'`).. then my path-finding algorithm finds a path on reduced graph `G'`, and i want to translate that path back to a path on `G` using the reverse steps that i took to go from `G` to `G'`. does that make sense?